# AWK: search last column of INPUT.txt in TABLEs text and add correspond columns to INPUT.txt

Tags: shell-script, awk, perl

dear all
i have INPUT.txt
like this
(look at last column)

```
INPUT.txt
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 298320 310050 11730 j j
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 310050 311430 1380 ( a
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 311430 312080 650 ] ]
```

and two TABLE text like this.have two columns.

```
TABLE1.txt
j feat1
a feat2
.
.
.
```

and

```
TABLE2.txt
j sp1
a sp2
.
.
```

I want to add two columns to INPUT.txt.
search last column of INPUT.txt in TABLEs text and add correspond columns to INPUT.txt.
(i think can mearge TABLEs like j feat1 sp1)
and output like this

```
output.txt
CodeGender Age Grade Dialect Session Sentence Start End Length Phonemic     Phonetic feat sp
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 298320 310050 11730 j j feat1 sp1
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 310050 311430 1380 ( a feat2 sp2
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 311430 312080 650 ] ]
.
.
.
```

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU awk, then you could use a mutlidimensional version of the canonical `NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $NF in a {print $0, a[$NF]}` with the following modifications:

1. you can't use the `NR==FNR` trick to decide whether you are building the lookup table or using it; you will need to count how many files have been processed
2. you will need to loop over the primary index explicitly and test for the match key in each subarray

Ex.

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE{k++}
  k<3 {a[k][$1]=$2; next} 
  {nf = NF; for (l in a) {if ($nf in a[l]) {$(NF+1) = a[l][$nf]}}}
  {print}
' TABLE1.txt TABLE2.txt INPUT.txt 

63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 298320 310050 11730 j j feat1 sp1
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 310050 311430 1380 ( a feat2 sp2
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 311430 312080 650 ] ]
```

If you want column headers, print them in a `BEGIN` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk too

```
awk '
FILENAME!=fn{
  a[$1]=a[$1]FS$2
  next
}
$NF in a{
  $0=$0a[$NF]
}
1
' fn='INPUT.txt' TABLE1.txt TABLE2.txt INPUT.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by below 2 steps

step1

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next};{$(NF + 1)=a[FNR]}1' file1 input.txt  >> final_final.txt
```

step2

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$2;next};{$(NF + 1)=a[FNR]}1' file2 final_final.txt
```

output

```
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 298320 310050 11730 j j feat1 sp1
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 310050 311430 1380 ( a feat2 sp2
63 M 27 BS/BA TEHRANI 3 4 311430 312080 650 ] ]
```